# Filter layer in web map via a URL

Tags: filter, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-portal, url, integration

I have a browser-based work order management system (Maximo 7.6.1.1).

I want a user to be able to **execute a URL** in Maximo that would open a web map and **filter a layer**.

For example, tell the web map to filter a layer based on a list of IDs:

```
wonum=WO1778,WO1772,WO1763
```

**How can I trigger the Portal web map to filter a layer via a URL?**

Answer (score 1):

I think the [Group Filter Widget](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-group-filter.htm) can filter layers based on parameters in a URL:

> Optionally, you can define filter values using URL parameters. To
>   configure the URL, it must be in the following format:
>   `https://<domain>/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=<itemid>&groupfilter={"<group name>":["<value>","<value>",...]}`

---

*Unfortunately, I don't think simple [URL parameters](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/use/app-url-parameters.htm) (for a single layer) can do this.*